# Where is the mission "Draugnet" located?

Tags: the-secret-world

I'm thought I had cleared out all of the missions in Kingsmouth, but according to my Achievements list, I'm missing one for the **Town Council** achievement. Specifically, I haven't done the quest entitled "**Draugnet**".

Where is this mission located? Which NPC or object starts it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Draugnet** mission is obtained from Deputy Andy, on the roof of the Sheriff's department in Kingsmouth.  (If you've already cleared the rest of the content in Kingsmouth, it should be a cakewalk.)